# Получить сообщение по IMAP C#

Tags: c#, imap

Здравствуйте вопрос по получению смс по имапу, получаю письмо так

```
try
            {
                string imap = GetDomain(login.Text); // Получаем imap сервер из конфига по полю Login
                using ( var client = new MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient())
                {
                    client.Connect(imap, 993, true); // Конект к серверу IMap первое значение это название сервера,второе это порт сервера и третье используется ли SSL подключение
                    client.Authenticate(login.Text, password.Text); // Авторизируемся данными из полей
                    client.Inbox.Open(MailKit.FolderAccess.ReadWrite); // Открываем папку Inbox с правами Read Write
                    for ( int i = client.Inbox.Count - 1; i < client.Inbox.Count; i++) // Получаем ID последнего сообщения
                    {
                        var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(i); // Получаем сообщение по ID в данном случае мы получаем id самого нового сообщения
                        richTextBox1.AppendText(message.Body.ToString()); // Выводит тело сообщение в RichBox
                        client.Inbox.AddFlags(i, MailKit.MessageFlags.Deleted, false); // Удаляем сообщение.
                    }
                    for(int i = 0; i < client.Inbox.Count; i++) // Перебираем все ID сообщений
                    {
                        var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(i); // Получаем сообщение по списку от самого последнего по самое новое
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Авторизация не удалась!");
            }
```

В теле сообщения я не могу найти ссылку которую нужно получить, хотя если смотреть в почтовом клиенте thunderbird он грузит сообщение и нужные данные там есть, но если открыть исходное тело сообщения в thunderbird, то нужных данных в нем тоже нет.
Пример, на картинке есть кнопка и по ней находится ссылка которую нужно получить, скриншот сделан с почтового клиента
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а в теле сообщения которое я получаю, ссылки нет, то есть не все данные получаю или сообщение потом как то генерируется

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества обновил вопрос

Comment: У сообщения 2 тела - HTML и Text, быть может не в том теле ищете.

Comment: Нашел уже что нужно, спасибо за ответ. Нужно было искать в теле HTML, то есть richTextBox1.AppendText(message.HtmlBody.ToString());

Comment: Зачем для string вызывать ToString() если оно и так string? Отвыкайте на автомате его втыкать.

Comment: @aepot по привычке поставил, пишу при помощи leaf xnet библиотеки в ней ToString нужен и здесь на автомате указал